# Searching for multiple strings in an NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, string, nsstring

Is it possible in Objective C to search an NSString for a number of different strings at the same time?

For example, I want to search for all occurrences of the strings "good", "great", "awesome", "incredible", "fantastic" and "brilliant" in a very long string.

My first though is to use `NSString:rangeOfString`: and cycle through multiple times (once for each string) but it strikes me that with longer sets of strings, this may become inefficient and slow.

Is there an in-built way of searching for multiple strings like this, or should I create my own method?

**EDIT: The results are in!**

After finding some time to benchmark, I found that the RegEx method is indeed slower (more than 2x slower) than the looping `rangeInString` method. The numbers, for your delectation, are as follows:

With a list of **150,000 words** (~1103,500 characters) and **20 match-words**, with **5412 matches present**

NSString:rangeInString search = **231.077ms**
Regular Expression search = **530.113ms**

Comment: at a first glance I'm afraid you will have to "manually" iterate, but I hope someone will prove me wrong

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I just did :)

Comment: @H2CO3, good answer, even though as you correctly pointed out, a regex will probably be slower ;)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Yes... and I didn't want to be personal, but I *hate* regexes. They cheated on me once terribly, and I can hardly forget it :P

Comment: yes, surely possible, probably you will need to run `–rangeOfString:` method on asynchronous threads many times as you just want, and it is almost the same. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it strikes me that with longer sets of strings, this may become inefficient and slow.

So, have you benchmarked it? If not, then you don't have the right to judge it as "inefficient" and "slow". Premature optimization is evil. Just stick with those nice and simple for loops and the `- [NSString rangeOfString:]` method.

---

**But:** to actually answer your question, it's not *impossible* to avoid the manual looping. If you use `NSRegularExpression` with a regex like `good|great|awesome`, then you can find all occurrences in one pass. **The use of regular expressions would probably be slower than a simple string search, though.**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. 

I didn't mean to **judge** it as inefficient and slow, only to suggest that the structure of my initial idea **may** be wasteful, since for a list of n strings, it takes n passes to do something that could be done with fewer iterations. 

Looks like I'll be enjoying an exercise in algorithms by making my own method and take some benchmarks :)

Comment: @sleeke Yes, actually benchmarking the code is worth more than a day of speculation by highest-scoring SO users :) The idea is that the CPU always knows better how fast it does stuff that anyone.

Comment: Agreed, but for a personal project, posting a question on SO in the morning and leaving it for discussion is a much better idea on a workday ;) Time consuming algorithm design and benchmarking is a thing best done in my spare time :)

Comment: @sleeke I don't want to solicit non-constructive debate, but writing a simple benchmark for this specific case should not take more than 10 minutes. (Also, please consider accepting my answer if it helped.)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are so widely used that the implementation will be efficient.  Specifically, a regex match will traverse the input string **once**.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = 
  [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: @"(good|great|...)"  
                                            options: NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                              error: ...];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString: string
                                  options: 0
                                    range: NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
  ...
```

Here is a test snippet:

```
  NSString *string = @"not good nor great";

  // as above
  for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
    NSLog (@"Match: %@", match);
```

produces:

```
2013-08-22 10:21:11.644 foo[2454:707] Match: <NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x7fc954301650>{4, 4}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x7fc9543001c0> (good|great) 0x1}
2013-08-22 10:21:11.644 foo[2454:707] Match: <NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x7fc954301540>{13, 5}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x7fc9543001c0> (good|great) 0x1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, internally the NSString is a data blob of unichars. You could retrieve a pointer to that and then have multiple queues search parts of it, though you'd have to make sure that you divide on white space characters so that miss a word part of two ranges.

Comment: There are NSStrings that internally aren't "a data blob of unichars". Those would have to be converted to UTF-16 when requesting the character data. Anyway, implementing string search using raw unicode code fragments is complex.